# How to deploy services (WMS and WFS) in port 80 and geoserver admin in diferent port(e.g. 8080)

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, tomcat

How can I configure my WMS and WFS to be in different port of my GeoServer admin?

The idea is to have a GeoServer admin internal which provides public services. In other words the idea is to configure my server application allowing internal access to GeoServer admin and public access to WMS/WFS services.

How can I do this? This is something that I have to set on tomcat( server.xml ) or I may change this configuration directly on GeoServer admin?

I think that this could be done by using "Proxy Base URL" on Global Settings for OGC Services. Am I following the right way?

Comment: You probably want to proxy using Apache http server.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is with a Reverse Proxy in front of GeoServer.

You can do it with Nginx.

Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/thanhleviet/3040490

The 'proxy base URL' setting in GeoServer allows you to tell GeoServer that it is behind one of these proxies, and adjusts all it's WMS Capabilities URLs and such (from my understanding).